# Execute jQuery file from ABAP using CL_JAVA_SCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, abap

I want to use CL_JAVA_SCRIPT in abap to execute a javascript file : jQuery.js which i get from url.
And this is my code :

```
REPORT ZCLIENT.  
DATA: LV_CLIENT TYPE REF TO IF_HTTP_CLIENT.  
DATA:lv_URL TYPE STRING .  
lv_URL  = 'https://resources/jquery.js'.  
* Create client  
   CALL METHOD CL_HTTP_CLIENT=>CREATE_BY_URL  
     EXPORTING  
       URL                = lv_URL  
     IMPORTING  
       CLIENT             = LV_CLIENT  
     EXCEPTIONS  
       ARGUMENT_NOT_FOUND = 1  
       PLUGIN_NOT_ACTIVE  = 2  
       INTERNAL_ERROR     = 3  
       OTHERS             = 4.  
   IF SY-SUBRC NE 0.  
     MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO  
       WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.  
   ENDIF.  
*   LV_CLIENT->REQUEST->SET_CONTENT_TYPE(  
*       EXPORTING  
*         CONTENT_TYPE = 'application/javascript; charset=UTF-8'  
*         ).  
   CALL METHOD LV_CLIENT->REQUEST->SET_FORMFIELD_ENCODING  
     EXPORTING  
       FORMFIELD_ENCODING = LV_CLIENT->REQUEST->CO_ENCODING_URL.  
* Get request:  
   CALL METHOD LV_CLIENT->SEND  
     EXCEPTIONS  
       HTTP_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE = 1  
       HTTP_INVALID_STATE         = 2  
       HTTP_PROCESSING_FAILED     = 3  
       OTHERS                     = 4.  
   IF SY-SUBRC NE 0.  
     MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO  
       WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.  
   ENDIF.  
* Prepare client-receive:  
   CALL METHOD LV_CLIENT->RECEIVE  
     EXCEPTIONS  
       HTTP_COMMUNICATION_FAILURE = 1  
       HTTP_INVALID_STATE         = 2  
       HTTP_PROCESSING_FAILED     = 3  
       OTHERS                     = 4.  
* Get HTML:  
DATA EV_DATA TYPE STRING.  
CONSTANTS co_line_size TYPE i VALUE 150.  
TYPES: t_line TYPE c LENGTH co_line_size.  
DATA: l_string TYPE string,  
      lt_lines TYPE TABLE OF t_line.  
FIELD-SYMBOLS: <l_line> TYPE t_line.  
   EV_DATA = LV_CLIENT->RESPONSE->GET_CDATA( ).  
"   compile js  
data GET_VALUE type STRING.  
data JS_PROCESSOR type ref to CL_JAVA_SCRIPT.  
data SOURCE type STRING.  
concatenate  EV_DATA SOURCE into SOURCE SEPARATED BY cl_abap_char_utilities=>cr_lf.  
JS_PROCESSOR = CL_JAVA_SCRIPT=>CREATE( ).  
JS_PROCESSOR->COMPILE( SCRIPT_NAME = 'TEST_GET.JS'  
  SCRIPT =  EV_DATA ).  
if JS_PROCESSOR->LAST_CONDITION_CODE <> 0.  
write: / 'Error in COMPILE',  
  JS_PROCESSOR->LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE.  
else.  
write / 'JavaScript was compiled'.  
endif.  
skip.  
JS_PROCESSOR->EXECUTE(  
exporting SCRIPT_NAME = 'TEST_GET.JS' ).  
if JS_PROCESSOR->LAST_CONDITION_CODE <> 0.  
write: / 'Error in EXECUTE',  
  JS_PROCESSOR->LAST_ERROR_MESSAGE.  
else.  
write / 'JavaScript was executed'.  
endif.  
skip.
```

my file is well compiled but When executing my code i'm getting some errors like "window is not defined" .

How should resolve the problem

Comment: You are aware that this is executing the code in the ABAP server context which ist NOT a browser?

Comment: @vwegert yes i think that the problem is caused by the window variable, is there any other solution to execute my jquery file ?

Comment: Your approach to the problem is fundamentally wrong. What do you want to achieve by "executing" test_get.js?

Comment: @MikaelG i have to execute a js file from abap and this js file need jquery to be well executed

Comment: Your js file should do something, right? Exactly what? Even though I don't know what it should do, my advice is to rewrite the logic inside "test_get.js" to ABAP. If you insist on javascript - get rid of jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library designed to work with the browser's document object model (DOM) and it used for the UI, animations, client side logic, etc. It is built on top of the DOM and all functionality depends on that, trying to execute the jQuery.js file on an ABAP system will not work as there is no browser and there is no DOM for jQuery to interact with.

You can find further information on the ABAP server and what it does and does not do at the SAP website [ABAP Application Server](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/fc/eb2e8a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) page.