# Executed JS via CL_JAVA_SCRIPT fails with "obj has no properties"

Tags: javascript, jquery, abap

I'm using ABAP report to execute a Javascript file using the CL_JAVA_SCRIPT, my file uses JQuery so i'm executing jQuery (no_dom) at the beginning than i execute my file.
But i'm getting an error : obj has no properties.

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
    var value,
      i = 0,
      length = obj.length,                //<============= HERE
      isArray = isArraylike( obj );
....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute jQuery file from ABAP using CL\_JAVA\_SCRIPT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35148676/execute-jquery-file-from-abap-using-cl-java-script)

Answer (score 0):

I just using :

```
Object.size = function(obj) {
    var size = 0, key;
    for (key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
    }
    return size;
};

// Get the size of an object
var size = Object.size(myArray);
```

and it works :)